# Can we always produce a bijective from from an uncountable set $A$ to an uncountable set $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we always produce a bijective from from an uncountable set $A$ to an uncountable set $B$ ? Assume $A, B \subset \Bbb R$

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both Borel sets, then YES.

Comment: See this possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650654/set-in-between-integers-and-reals/

Answer (score 3):

Whether there is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ strictly smaller than $\mathbb{R}$ and strictly greater than $\mathbb{N}$ is not provable in the standard set theory, even with the axiom of choice. So the answer is either "no" (in general) or "it depends" (on the chosen model).

Answer (score 0):

If you by "produce a bijective" means actually writing it down, constructively, then the answer must certailnly be NO.